# How to use TRegistry in Delphi for ALL subkeys of subkeys and values of Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\?

Tags: delphi, search, key

I'm new to using the TRegistry for Delphi.  I've looked at all the documents on http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry , but I'm still scratching my head on how to look up subkeys of subkeys... or what am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to open up the key to all the subkeys of Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\ then open those subkeys up and for each subkey that I want to find in the subkeys like Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}\0000 then read those values, then find the next subkey Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}\0001 and read those values... I'm doing a search for NetCfgInstanceId in the subkeys to match the wifi GUID.  Then I wish to delete/create a key in the same key area as it is found in NetCfgInstanceId key area.

*Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?*

Program Output and **Source code at the very bottom**:

```
***************** SPLIT *****************
Name:--Wi-Fi 3-- inc_number=1
Name:--Wi-Fi-- inc_number=2
Name:--Wi-Fi 8-- inc_number=3
Description:--D-Link DWA-171 Wireless AC Dual Band Adapter-- inc_number=1
Description:--Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265-- inc_number=2
Description:--Realtek RTL8811AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2.0 Network Adapter-- inc_number=3
GUID:--de0b90f8-8853-4668-a8b5-54be3363bc45-- inc_number=1
GUID:--73cf37c1-3899-4aca-b02f-9a56bd804e1e-- inc_number=2
GUID:--ccfd0ae1-5f95-4f1d-94aa-50ab106a246b-- inc_number=3
Physical address:--**:**:**:**:**:**-- inc_number=1
Physical address:--**:**:**:**:**:**-- inc_number=2
Physical address:--**:**:**:**:**:**-- inc_number=3
Read:
C:\Users\**\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\**\Win32\Debug>
WifiInterfaces[1].GUID ={de0b90f8-8853-4668-a8b5-54be3363bc45}
{05f5cfe2-4733-4950-a6bb-07aad01a3a84}
...
{fe8f1572-c67a-48c0-bbac-0b5c6d66cafb}
------------------------SEARCHING--------------------------------
TmpKey--SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{05f5cfe2-4733-4950-a6bb-07aad01a3a84}
KEY DOES NOT EXISTS

!!SAYS ALL OF THEM DO NOT EXISTS!!  There is like a hundred here I had to delete because your limited on how much you can post.

TmpKey--SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{fe8f1572-c67a-48c0-bbac-0b5c6d66cafb}
KEY DOES NOT EXISTS
```

---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, gtCommandPrompt,
  System.Win.Registry;

type
   Tinterfaces = Record
     Name : string;
     Description  : string;
     GUID  : string;
     Physical_Address  : string;
     //SSID  : string[100];
   end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CommandPrompt1: TCommandPrompt;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure CommandPrompt1ReadCommandPrompt(OutPut: string);
    procedure CommandPrompt1WriteCommandPrompt(OutPut: string);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  WifiInterfaces : array[1..20] of Tinterfaces;
  NumOfInterfaces : integer = 0;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure pSplitIT(BreakString, BaseString: string; StringList: TStrings; ForceRightSideOfBreakString: boolean = false; Offset: integer = 1);
var
  EndOfCurrentString: byte;
  //TempStr: string;
  iLengthenBreakString: integer;
begin
  StringList.Clear;

  iLengthenBreakString := 0;

  // if the BreakString is greater than 1, it will force the break to be on the right side
  // of the BreakString instead of the left side
  if ForceRightSideOfBreakString = true then
    if length(BreakString) > 0 then iLengthenBreakString := length(BreakString);

  repeat
    if Offset = 1 then
      EndOfCurrentString := Pos(BreakString, BaseString) + iLengthenBreakString
    else
      EndOfCurrentString := Pos(BreakString, BaseString, Offset) + iLengthenBreakString;

    if EndOfCurrentString > length(BaseString) then EndOfCurrentString := length(BaseString);

    if EndOfCurrentString = 0 then
      StringList.add(BaseString)
    else
      StringList.add(Copy(BaseString, 1, EndOfCurrentString - 1));
    BaseString := Copy(BaseString, EndOfCurrentString + length(BreakString), length(BaseString) - EndOfCurrentString);

  until EndOfCurrentString = 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CommandPrompt1.cmdWriteln('netsh wlan show interface');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registry        : TRegistry;
  i : integer;
  SubKeyNames, SubKeyNames2: TStringList;
  Name, Name2, Key, TmpKey: string;
begin
  i := 1;
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  Try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Registry.Access := KEY_READ;

    //NumOfInterfaces  integer

    memo1.Lines.Add('WifiInterfaces[1].GUID ={'+WifiInterfaces[i].GUID+'}');

    // Key := 'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{'+WifiInterfaces[i].GUID+'}';
    Key := 'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\';

    if Registry.KeyExists(Key) = false then
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\ key does not exist');
      exit;
    end;


    SubKeyNames := TStringList.Create;
    SubKeyNames2 := TStringList.Create;

    if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key) = true then
    begin
      Registry.GetKeyNames(SubKeyNames);
      for Name in SubKeyNames do
        memo1.Lines.Add(Name);
    end
    else
      memo1.Lines.Add('unable to Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly');

    memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------SEARCHING--------------------------------');

    //Registry.Access := ;

    for Name in SubKeyNames do
      begin
        SubKeyNames2.Clear;

        TmpKey := Key + Name;

        memo1.Lines.Add('TmpKey--'+TmpKey);

        if Registry.KeyExists(TmpKey) = true then
        begin

          if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(TmpKey) = true then
          begin
            Registry.GetKeyNames(SubKeyNames2);
            for Name2 in SubKeyNames2 do
              memo1.Lines.Add(Name);
          end
          else
            memo1.Lines.Add('unable to Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly '+TmpKey);
        end
        else
          memo1.Lines.Add('KEY DOES NOT EXISTS');
      end;

    SubKeyNames.Free;
    SubKeyNames2.Free;

  Finally
    Registry.Free;
  End;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CommandPrompt1.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CommandPrompt1.Stop;
end;

function FindString(FirstSubString, SecondSubString, MainString: String; var StringFound: String; PosOffset: integer = 0): integer;
var I, I1 : integer;
begin
  StringFound := '';
  //result := false;
  I := Pos( String(FirstSubString), String(MainString), PosOffset);
  if (I > 0) then
  begin
    I1 := Pos( String(SecondSubString), String(MainString), I);
    if (I1 > 0) then
    begin
      StringFound := copy(MainString, (I+length(FirstSubString)), (I1-(I+length(FirstSubString))));
      result := I1;
    end
    else
      result := 0;
  end
  else
    result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.CommandPrompt1ReadCommandPrompt(OutPut: string);
var i,inc_number : integer;
    MainStr, StringFound : String;
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add('Read:' + OutPut);
  if Output.Contains('GUID                   :') = true then
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('***************** SPLIT *****************');

    MainStr := StringReplace(Output, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);

    i := 1;
    inc_number := 1;

    while i > 0 do
    begin
      i := FindString('Name                   : ','Description',MainStr,StringFound,i);
      if i > 0 then
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add('Name:--' + Trim(StringFound) + '-- inc_number='+IntToStr(inc_number));
          WifiInterfaces[inc_number].Name := Trim(StringFound);
          inc(inc_number);
        end;
    end;

    i := 1;
    inc_number := 1;

    while i > 0 do
    begin
      i := FindString('Description            : ','GUID',MainStr,StringFound,i);
      if i > 0 then
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add('Description:--' + Trim(StringFound) + '-- inc_number='+IntToStr(inc_number));
          WifiInterfaces[inc_number].Description := Trim(StringFound);
          inc(inc_number);
        end;
    end;

    i := 1;
    inc_number := 1;

    while i > 0 do
    begin
      i := FindString('GUID                   : ','Physical address',MainStr,StringFound,i);
      if i > 0 then
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add('GUID:--' + Trim(StringFound) + '-- inc_number='+IntToStr(inc_number));
          WifiInterfaces[inc_number].GUID := Trim(StringFound);
          inc(inc_number);
        end;
    end;

    NumOfInterfaces := inc_number;

    i := 1;
    inc_number := 1;

    while i > 0 do
    begin
      i := FindString('Physical address       : ','State',MainStr,StringFound,i);
      if i > 0 then
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add('Physical address:--' + Trim(StringFound) + '-- inc_number='+IntToStr(inc_number));
          WifiInterfaces[inc_number].Physical_Address := Trim(StringFound);
          inc(inc_number);
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CommandPrompt1WriteCommandPrompt(OutPut: string);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add('Write:' + OutPut);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Okay, still working on this problem, but found that I could extract the information using command prompt `reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\ /s /f *de0b90f8-8853-4668-a8b5-54be3363bc45*`  reg query will search for the de0b90f8-8853-4668-a8b5-54be3363bc45 and return me the NetCfgInstanceId that it finds the directory in.  Then I can use that full directory to modify, add, delete values in that directory.  For some reason I can't seem to program it to do it, so the work around is using command prompt.

Comment: The command prompt component I'm using I found here: https://github.com/War3Evo/gtDelphi/tree/master/CommandPrompt

Answer (score 1):

The question includes too much code. Separate out an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that does one thing and describe the expected results vs what you see. Here if I manually take a GUID from that section of the registry and put it in code both KeyExists and OpenKey work.

Do that for each functional part of your code to isolate the problem.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  reg : TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if (not reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{14b62f50-3f15-11dd-ae16-0800200c9a66}\')) then
      MessageDlg(IntToStr(reg.LastError) +' : ' + reg.LastErrorMsg,mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This code can be simplified further by removing the call to `TRegistry.KeyExists()` completely and then using the [`TRegistry.LastError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.LastError) properly to know whether `TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly()` fails because the key didn’t exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Point taken. Example updated.

Comment: The error code I get is: "The system cannot find the file specified"  even though I know it exists in the registry.  SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\  I added the missing backslash thinking that is what was missing, but that didn't help.  I've even tried to run it with elevated privileges and that did not help either.   Same error code for all of them.